# VBA - How to declare "Cell" variable

Tags: vba, excel, variables, declare

Apologies for the potentially very easy to answer question. I was trawling through some code on the site regarding how you search for a row and paste it in another worksheet, the code being the one below:

```
Sub Test()
For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("J:J")
  If Cell.Value = "131125" Then
    matchRow = Cell.Row
    Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

I was wondering what the "Cell" should be declared as, as in:

```
Dim Cell As ...
```

I'm aware that without "Option Explicit", this is irrelevant, but I'm curious nonetheless, so please do help and explain if you can.

Thank you for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, `cell` is a `range`, so

```
dim cell as range
```

And: ***Always*** use `Option Explicit`

Answer (score 2):

Walking over a Range yields a Range so `Dim Cell As Range`

If in doubt ask VBA: `msgbox TypeName(Cell)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Range`. They are somewhat interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but that is horrible code and it offends the eyes. Find would be better, but just in the interest of better understanding

```
 Sub Test()
 Dim Cell as Range
 For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("J:J")
      If Cell.Value = "131125" Then
          Cell.EntireRow.copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").range("a" & cell.row)
          'You might want to exit here if there's only one value to find with 
          'Exit For
      End If
 Next
```

End Sub